# give id to sessions with a mark at the first row of a new session

Tags: r, dataframe

```
df <- data.frame(mark_new =c(1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1))
> df
    mark_new
1         1
2         0
3         0
4         1
5         0
6         0
7         0
8         0
9         0
10        1
11        0
12        1
```

Every time a 1 appears, it means a new session starts. I want to give each session an id. The result should look like this:

```
>df1
    mark_new id
1         1  1
2         0  1
3         0  1
4         1  2
5         0  2
6         0  2
7         0  2
8         0  2
9         0  2
10        1  3
11        0  3
12        1  4
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `cumsum` on the logical column (`df$mark_new == 1` - here I am assuming that there could be other values in addition to 0 and 1)

```
df$id <- cumsum(df$mark_new==1)
df$id
#[1] 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 4
```

If the 'mark_new' column is binary, as @thelatemail mentioned, we can just do the `cumsum` on the whole column instead of converting to 'logical'

```
df$id <- cumsum(df$mark_new)
```

---

If we use `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   mutate(id = cumsum(mark_new == 1)
```

Comment: @thelatemail Yes, just in case the OP have other values.